# Attach to a module in another process and invoke a public method?

Tags: c#, process

I don't know if this is possible for security reasons, but it might be.

I have discovered an issue in one of our applications and a way to fix it is to invoke a public method on an in-process module.

So, my application (which I cannot modify) is using a referenced dll called 'SSOSettingsFileReader.dll', in the SSOSettingsFileReader.dll is a public method named 'ClearCache'. I want to write a console app that cycles through all processes, searches for modules in each process named SSOSettingsFileReader and invoke 'ClearCache' on each.

Is this possible?

So far, I can get the module:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process p in processes) {
    if (p.ProcessName == "BTSNTSvc") {
        ProcessModuleCollection modules = p.Modules;

        foreach (ProcessModule m in modules) {
            if (m.ModuleName == "SSOSettingsFileReader.dll") {
                // What to do here? 
                // SSOSettingsFileReader sso = SomeWayToConvertModule(m)ToSSOSettingsFileReader();
                // sso.ClearCache();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

p.s. I'm using VS2005 with .Net2.0 but not limited to it

Comment: It would be easier to inject some IL where you need it in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting code into processes isn't exactly the most reliable way to fix bugs.  If you're sure there's no other alternative, it is possible.

[CreateRemoteThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the heart of what you need, that's how you execute code in a remote process.  That function requires a thread entry point, so you'll probably have to compile a wrapper around the `ClearCache` function and add that into the target process.  The MSDN docs cover the security requirements.  In general there shouldn't be a problem with a user injecting this call into a process which they own.